# Zoomable Treemap overflowing labels

Tags: d3.js

I have taken the d3 ZoomableTreeMap example from [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) and applied my own data to it. I am now trying to stop the text from overflowing outside of rectangle boundaries. As you can see in the following screenshot, this makes the vis very ugly and difficult to read, especially in the bottom right region.

[image]

I have tried setting the css property **overflow: hidden** for a few different elements but it seems to have no effect. Any idea why?

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

text {
  overflow: hidden;
}

rect {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: In SVG, you need to define a `viewPort` as well (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/overflow). You could also add a `clipPath` of the same dimensions as the rectangles.